# macOS reports updated printer software after installing manufacturer software

Tags: macos, install, software-update, driver

Until today, my Mac Mini, running Catalina (10.15.4) was using the system provided driver to print to and scan from my HP OfficeJet Pro 8620. This also meant that I couldn't use all of the features offered on the printer via its built-in display, for example, triggering a scan on the device rather than from the computer, sending faxes from the computer to the device, etc..

Today I was having problems with scanning so I installed the HP provided software to resolve the issue and regain some of the printers capabilities. Everything worked fine with the printing and scanning after installing the HP provided software.

Now, macOS is reporting that there is an update for the printer software on my Mac Mini, see below.

[image]

I'm worried if I install this, it will overwrite what I installed from HP. I also don't want it to keep pestering me about the HP Software update.

**Should I let macOS install the updated software?  Will doing so overwrite what I installed from HP?**

**If I shouldn't run the update, how do I set macOS to ignore this particular software update?**

Comment: This could just be a driver update for extended compatibility. Try installing and if it doesn’t work, you might be able to reset the printer to factory defaults.

Comment: I went through and installed the update, then my scanner stopped working again.  So I uninstalled the HP software.  Re-added the printer through system preferences using the O.S. drivers and the scanner worked.  Guess I may have to live without some of the features provided by the printer for a bit until I can figure this out.